# Fastest way to generate a hash key for an int[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

For instance `int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

I want to convert this into `int a  = 123456789;`

I am intending to use this as hash key.

My idea is to convert the array into a string using `Arrays.toString`and then convert it back to an integer. But I think that is not a good solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's great about base 10?

Comment: If there are any better ways to create a unique integer for a unique int[] array, that would be awesome!

Comment: But it has to be really fast. I don't think converting or iterating through is good since I would be using this for a search algorithm.

Comment: so how can you tell `{12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` from `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` ? Either your idea is bad or you haven't given us all of the constraints.

Comment: @John3136 Yeah I haven;t thought about that. The arrays are the same size though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use [`Arrays.hashCode(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-int:A-) to get a hash code based on the array contents.

Answer (score 2):

For a real hash I would use [`Arrays.hashCode(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28int[]%29), but your requested function can be done with one line -

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(array)
    .replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,\\ ", ""));
System.out.println(a);
```

Output is

```
123456789
```

Comment: Try that with int[] array = new int[] { -1, -1 }; and you'll get a NumberFormatException

Comment: @Adam Bonus, it fails fast!

Comment: Also NumberFormatException with int[] array = new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1 };

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.hashCode(int[])`  would be helpful..